# Update UI control (TextBlock) inside routine

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How can update UI inside a routine?
For example:

```
Private sub foo()
    myTextBlock.Text = "Phase 1"
    DoSomething
    myTextBlock.Text = "Phase 2"
    DoSomething
End Sub
```

To be more specific, and a bit more complex, phase 1 is a file download with WebClient, phase 2 is execute that file, but can start only when download is completed.

Comment: You should use the *Async methods of the WebClient.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't see the UI update because your **DoSomething** Sub is executing in the Main (UI) thread. Try using Async/Await instead.

Below a simulation of a file download:

MainWinwow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test Window" Height="200" Width="400"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockControl" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
Class MainWindow
    Private Async Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        TextBlockControl.Text = "Downloading file..."
        Await Task.Run(Sub() DownloadFile())
        TextBlockControl.Text = "Reading file..."
        Await Task.Run(Sub() ReadFile())
        TextBlockControl.Text = "Finished :)"
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReadFile()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DownloadFile()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Also consider using Binding, in WPF, Binding is the way.

Answer (score -1):

WPF is all about databinding but yes, you can set it in code as well.

First, give your control a name in the XAML:

```
    <TextBlock
        x:Name="myTextBlock">
    </TextBlock>
```

To use `x:Name` you, have to include the following namespace

```
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

Now, you can use your control (in this case `myTextBlock`) in code:

```
    myTextBlock.Text = "Phase 1"
```

Comment: My problem is not how to can I change control properties but how to refresh UI before the end of the routine, as we did with DoEvents in old VB6

Comment: @Mary: fixed, thanks. @MassimoSpinelli, then please look at your question again and add that information for anyone else in here. "How can update UI inside a routine?" does not say anything about threading problems and legacy workarounds with `DoEvents()` in VB6 at all.